# Can i convert a string into a method?

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

Ok if you don't under stand the title, let me example.

lets say I have a variable called "money" which is in class "wallet". Normally I would just do this to get the value;

```
 trace(wallet.money);
```

but if I had 10 different money variables like money_1 , money_2 etc...

so can i make a string which original value as "wallet.money_" then just add the number at the end. so the function would look like this

```
public function getmoney(num:Number):Number
{
var word:String = "wallet.money_" + num.toString();

return // this would be where i return the value of the money variable.

}
```

is this possible or not?

Comment: functions [parseFloat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#parseFloat()) and parseInt convert a `string` to a `Number` parseFloat keeps decimals(floats) parseInt does not

Comment: Are you familiar with `Array`s which would allow the form: `wallet.money[num]` ?

Comment: @AlexK. Well, it was a wondering type of question. i just wanted to see if it could be done more than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference it like this:

wallet["money_" + i]

i is an int - use int for index number not Number.